# Is it possible to select and override an rgb color style using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, greasemonkey

I want to select and override a `div` with an `rgb` color style. Normally, I would specify the `class` name and be done with it; but in this case, the `div` uses a nonsense `class` name.

It looks like the following:

`<div class="_RanDomGibBeRish" style="color: rgb(215, 218, 220);">Null</div>`

Can I use JS to parse the DOM for this `rgb` style attribute and substitute it for a different color?

Comment: You'll have to find some way to uniquely identify the element - if not by the class name, then by its other attributes, or its textContent, or by its location in the DOM. Please post more context, or a link to the page, for a proper answer

Comment: Can you assign an `ID` to this div? If yes, then use CSS to define it. If no, then if you must be aware of the DOM hierarchy for the JS to grab the div. Be mindful that if the DOM hierarchy changes, the JS needs to be updated, so using JS is not a very robust solution

Comment: The example I gave is in a heavily nested set of `div`s with no selectable `ID`s or `class` names. It's just `div`s and nonsense words except for a few static parts like the unique `rgb(215, 218, 220)` `color` style.

Comment: You need to either link to the target page and/or provide a proper [mcve].   As, it currently is, it's a duplicate.  See the linked answers.

Comment: Maybe this [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/sehv1Ldr/) could be of some help? I'm not really sure how many elements you are wanting to target or if you have a specific `rgb` you want to target.